# Detect http or https failed using $_SERVER

Tags: php

I want to check whether the url is via https or http, but i tested on https://www.techinasia.com/, it return me "http://" instead.

```
$url = http://example.com;
    if($html = @DOMDocument::loadHTML(file_get_contents($url))) {

    ...
    ...

                  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off')
                    {
                      echo "https://";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      echo "http://";

                    }

                }
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: One of those `$_SERVER`s is actually `$_SEREVER`.

Comment: If your page is blank, than there must be an error in your code. Enable the PHP error reporting to see what is the PHP error.

Comment: @icktoofay that typo I fixed doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is telling you whether *your* page got accessed by http or https; not whether another page you are loading is. For that, just do simple string matching on the URL.

Comment: Use `parse_url($url)` and test whether `$parsed['scheme'] == 'https'`